# Excel Matrix Condition - Is there a faster way?

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I'd like to get some data depending on multiple entries.

I'm using the **"NB.SI.ENS()"** which is **"COUNTIFS()"** in English if I'm not mistaken.

I have multiple entries, which would represent a 3D array since I'm using 3 Sources. Those Sources are an **Activity**, a **Project**, and a **Date**.

For each one, I need to count the triplets (**Activity**, **Project**, **Date**). My exemple in the Image shows **3** for the Number of **Tests** in **Project 1** on the **10**th Month.

[image: This is the representation]

With two Sources, the **COUNTIFS()** functions work okay. I can do this with as much **COUNTIFS()** as there are intersection between Rows and Columns from the two Sources (for instance, **Activities**, and **Projects**)

With 3 entries, I need to make as much 2D arrays as there are datas in the third array.

I've chosen the **Dates** as the 3rd array, so I have 12 2D arrays.

This uses a lot of computation time from Excel when I'm getting over 200 ligns of data.

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you are trying to count Project wise entries for those 3 Development, Test & Mobilization,,, write ?? One Advice the Date should not use as criteria BCoz all rows have same date 01/10/2017.

Comment: Your are right, my image is not explicit enough. There are of course rows with different dates. I've updated the exemple with other dates (November, December)

Answer (score 2):

I have a very dirty solution, but I have tried and can **get instant result for 600 rows of data**.

I have screen cap my setup for you (https://image.ibb.co/kqxvYR/tmp.png)

Basically, I have concatenated the three text together using a symbol, and only done COUNTIF for that column

Step by step:

1. Concatenate the 3 texts

   1. Using this command [**=CONCAT($A2," | ",$B2, " | ",$C2)**] for D2 (increase the number by 1 each row)
   2. For instance : A2 = **Test**, B2 = **Project 1**, C2 = **01/10/2017**
   3. Now I got: **Tests | Project 1 | 01/10/2017**
2. When you need to search: Paste the wanted 3 items in separate place

   1. For instance: F10 = **Modelisation**, G10 = **Project 2**,  *I10* = **01/10/2017**
   2. Use 1.1 Command again [**=CONCAT($F10," | ",$G10, " | ",$I10)**] for F12
   3. Now F12 will look like this **Modelisation | Project 2 | 01/10/2017**
   4. You can get your result using this a much more simple COUNTIF Command: **=COUNTIF(D2:D14,F12)**
3. Now you might think that giving this ugly test *Modelisation | Project 2 | 01/10/2017* is not accpetabl

   1. You can use hide it using Excel formatting magic
   2. Drag over all the D column ugly text
   3. Right click > Format Cell
   4. Then Number tab > Custom
   5. Type in **;;;** in the textbox
   6. Then the ugly text is not visible to user anymore

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot. For 200 rows of data, I went from 10 seconds of computing time to 3 seconds

Comment: Glad it helps !

Comment: @NgSekLong, Solution is a Solution ultimately,, and you have done it in your way. Helper column is one of useful tools but many user don't like it. But I always appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 1):

After analysing your Screen Shot and the Query I've created a Solution which is Counting all three activities falling on different dates.Check this Screen Shot.

[image]

**Data Range is A434:D459**.

**First Formula in B449**.

=COUNTIFS($A$434:$A$446,"="&$A449,$B$434:$B$446,"="&$A$448,$C$434:$C$446,"="&B$448)

**Sceond Formula in B453**.

=COUNTIFS($A$434:$A$446,"="&$A453,$B$434:$B$446,"="&$A$452,$C$434:$C$446,"="&B$452)

**Third Formula in B457**.

=COUNTIFS($A$434:$A$446,"="&$A457,$B$434:$B$446,"="&$A$456,$C$434:$C$446,"="&B$456)

**Drag all Formulas 2 Columns Right then 2 Row Down.**

*Adjust the Data Range as your need*.

**Hope the help you, I've posted after is been tested by me.**

Comment: @Xhaltr, I've used the best possible method  to track down the activities falling in different dates in 2 segments because for better understanding.

Comment: You answer is interesting, but I don't understand how that's different from mine ? Could you be more precise ?

Comment: My solution is exactly what has been asked by you. I found it's the best method I can suggest you to Tabulate the Projects falling within the Dates. If you need other than this, just post the Screen Shot of the Output Format I'll create other one.